# How is it possible to know what caused an exception

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, exception

In the code I am implementing I have

```
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

And there is an execution path when the exception occurs
How can I know why the exception happened while debugging?
Use `GetExceptionInformation`?-Can it print the exception or give me exception`s data?

Comment: make your debugger break at the point where exceptions are thrown

Comment: Note that swallowing exceptions is not a good idea in general because you don't know whether the exception is recoverable (and if it is, how to recover from it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can go to `Debug > Exceptions` (in the menu). There's a checkbox for each exception type which enables you to break execution when the exception is thrown.